# maven execution of plugin goal?

Tags: java, maven

i am new to maven and learning how and when phases/goals get executed in plugin

Say i have below code snippet in my pom

```
 <plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.modello</groupId>
   <artifactId>modello-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.4</version>
 </plugin>
```

Now if i execute mvn install,  all phases(and all goals corresponding to each phase) of modello that comes prior to install will be executed. **Right?**

But if do below modification to introduce specific goal,  only one goal i.e java goal will be executed
(as it  under `generate-sources` phase which comes prior to `install` phase). **Is that correct?**

```
 <plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.modello</groupId>
   <artifactId>modello-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.4</version>
   <executions>
     <execution>
       <goals>
         <goal>java</goal>
       </goals>
     </execution>
   </executions>
 </plugin>
```

Comment: What would the _specific_ maven command to execute that "java" goal be if it was not "bound" to any phase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't work like that. First of all, please use `mvn verify` (instead of install), unless you really want your project to be copied to your local repository.

If you only specify a plugin, which is *not* part of the default lifecycle (e.g. maven-compiler-plugin is already specified for the default lifecycle, all jars need to compile, right?), nothing will happen. So you need to specify which goals need to be executed within an execution-block. In some cases the goal has a default phase to bind to, e.g. [modello:java](http://modello.codehaus.org/modello-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html) binds by default to the `generate-sources`-phase. In this case you don't have to specify a `<phase>` in the execution-block.

Comment: Thanks Robert. But how can i verify if a plugin is part of default lifecycle or not? For example :- I did not find it under modello docs? Another example is i could find entry of maven-checkstyle-plugin in my pom but did not find any goal element for it. Is it part of default lifecycle?

Comment: Second point is  if i have need to execute two goals of a plugin, do i need to specify two execution elements?

Comment: Per packaging type a set of plugins is bound to specific phases. http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html contains an overview at  the bottom.

Comment: The execution block allows multiple goals, so you don't have to, unless you don't like the phase to which they are bound.

Comment: Robert one last question which is very important to understand. I came across usage of sunfire plugin at http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/usage.html.
I see there, No goal is mentioned in usage example.It says "The Surefire Plugin can be invoked by calling the test phase of the build lifecycle"
Does it mean we can just specify the plugin entry without Goal in POM. While calling mvn phase (in this case mvn test), goals of sunfire
plugin which binds to test phase will automatically be executed ?

Comment: Yes on the page in my prev. comment you should see that the surefire-plugin is *always* executed during the `test`-phase. For this plugin you don't need an execution block to configure this plugin